# How to install tensorflow for NVIDIA GPU RTX 2070 SUPER on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, xubuntu, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I have been trying to install Tensorflow for my new RTX 2070 Super. I have been following the following instructions:

#### steps

#### verify the system has a cuda-capable gpu

#### download and install the nvidia cuda toolkit and cudnn

#### setup environmental variables

#### verify the installation

### #

#### If you have previous installation remove it first.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt remove nvidia-*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*
```

#### to verify your gpu is cuda enable check

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

#### gcc compiler is required for development using the cuda toolkit. to verify the version of gcc install enter

```
gcc --version
```

## system update

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

## install other import packages

```
sudo apt-get install g++ freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
```

## first get the PPA repository driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
```

# installing CUDA-10.0

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install cuda-10-0 cuda-drivers
```

## setup your paths

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sudo ldconfig
```

## install cuDNN v7.5

## in order to download cuDNN you have to be regeistered here https://developer.nvidia.com/developer-program/signup

## then download cuDNN v7.5 form https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

```
CUDNN_TAR_FILE="cudnn-10.0-linux-x64-v7.5.0.56"
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.5.0.56/prod/10.0_20190219/cudnn-10.0-linux-x64-v7.5.0.56.tgz
tar -xzvf ${CUDNN_TAR_FILE}
```

## copy the following files into the cuda toolkit directory.

```
sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda-10.0/include
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcudnn*
```

## Finally, to verify the installation, check

```
nvidia-smi
nvcc -V
```

## install Tensorflow (an open source machine learning framework)

## I choose version 1.13.1 because it is stable and compatible with CUDA 10.0 Toolkit and cuDNN 7.5

pip3 install --user tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1

However, when when I type `nvidia-smi` I get the following:
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

I also tried to download the latest NVIDIA driver (440.35) but I had no success running the .run file. It kept giving me a message saying "The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally installed Tensorflow in my GeForce RTX 2070 Super with the following installations:

Ubuntu 18.04

CuDNN 7.5

CUDA 10.0

NVIDIA Driver Version 430.50

Then I just did `pip3 install --user tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1` using Conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

That gpu supports cuda 10.2, which is supported by driver version >=440.
It is possible that ubuntu 18.04 itself does not support that driver version, or doesn't have it in its official repo. This is why it is always better to directly install driver from nvidia website; using [*.run script](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
With your current setup, the performance will be suboptimal.
In that case, I recommend downloading python [wheels](https://github.com/mind/wheels) of necessary packages; or using Docker images with all [preinstalled](https://github.com/gw0/docker-keras) software.